# Picture showing lower?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, structure

I'm trying to make a document on Overleaf that includes pictures. I have the text and then (after having uploaded the picture) I include the code for a picture and write some more text after. Let's say, I want my pdf to look like TEXT A - picture - TEXT B. I also want my picture to be of size 12cm.

I have the following extract of my document then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/user/Desktop/images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}

\title{--}
\author{--}
\date{--}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

τον έτρεξα στο command window και το αποτέλεσμα που πήρα ήταν: % this is TEXT A

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=12cm]{cmdw.png}    % this is my image
\end{figure}

δηλαδή:
$$\frac{||x^{(15)}-x||}{||x||}\leq 6.8406\cdot 10^{-15}$$   % this is TEXT B and the end of the subsection
```

When I run this by itself in a new document, it works just fine and it has the structure TEXT A - picture - TEXT B.

Now, when I run it on my assignment document I have this specific problem: when the picture is 12cm as I want it, it won't fit in the margin that's left at the bottom of the page. So, when I compile it, the picture shows after TEXT B! If I use 8.5cm it fits in the margin, so it has my desired structure.

Also, when I use \quad commands for enough rows, so that the picture starts on the next page, it does appear with my desired structure of TEXT A - picture - TEXT B, but I was wondering if I can avoid using \quad and have the picture just show where I have it in my code! How can I make it so that it always appears where I write it?

Comment: the purpose of the `figure` environment is to specify a _float_ that may be moved and re-inserted to help with page breaking, so what you describe is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix, I do not have much time right now. (Not sure if I understand your question 100 %).

1. Add `\usepackage{float}`
2. Change `\begin{figure}[htp]` to `\begin{figure}[H]`.

For further reference, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275) for example.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It solved my problem!